# URL Regex - remove trailing slash from file name and end of URL?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have this regex problem and wondered if anyone could help me out?

If a user visits http://example.com/index.php/ how can i modify/add to my regex to prevent a trailing slash(s) at the end?

also

I currently have a page, called post.php that can be accessed like so http://example.com/reviews/reviewTitle/ and http://example.com/news/newsTitle/

again, how could I prevent this trailing slash?

Below is the regex I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^reviews/([^/\.]+)/?$ reviews/post.php?title=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.]+)/?$ news/post.php?title=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) index.php?page=$1
```

Note: Im also re-writing http://example.com/index.php?page=1 to http://example.com/page/1 etc, same question, how can I prevent a trailing slash?

Many thanks, I really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this rule after `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$    $1  [R=301]
RewriteRule ^reviews/([^/\.]+)$ reviews/post.php?title=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.]+)$ news/post.php?title=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) index.php?page=$1
```

**Edited** to show full set of rules

**Edited 2nd Time** Added in

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

above new rule to allow directorys to still be accessed without causing an infinite redirect loop

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but it causes http://example.com/reviews/reviewTitle or http://example.com/news/reviewTitle to not work at all (404 Not Found) and adding a trailing slash causes an Internal Server Error :/

Comment: Thanks again, but it now causes an infinite loop of redirects :/ (Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.)

Comment: Woo Hoo :D It's working now, although I added a / before the $1 to make it redirect to the root, as it was redirecting to the var/www/ folders. Thank you!

Comment: to fix that add RewriteBase / I'll post the full code above for you