# .htaccess - URL Regex - never ending loop issue?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I posted up a question about an hour ago asking a regex question about trailing slashes

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907130/url-regex-remove-trailing-slash-from-file-name-and-end-of-url)

And a very helpful person gave me this to redirect pages with a trailing slash to a page with none.

However I have just noticed **that it causes an infinite (never ending loop) of redirects if you try and access a folder**, as you go to say http://example.com/images the server (Apache) adds a trailing slash as its a directory, then the Regex removes the slash, redirects back to the http://example.com/images URL which then gets its slash added back on by Apache etc etc :/

Any Ideas as to how to modify the rule below to prevent this?

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$    $1  [R=301]
```

Many thanks, help always appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added in the line below just above my current **RewriteRule ^(.*)/$    $1  [R=301]** rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Thanks for the reply though limc :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$    $1  [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still get the "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." message :/